# HTML tags appearing during Excel Export

Tags: java, html

My application has a method that appends a list of strings into a StringBuffer, which is to be displayed on a webpage. I have used `<br>` and `\u2022` to ensure that each string is displayed one below the other with bullets. I have a method to export all these to an excel sheet. The Export method also uses this same method to get the values. In the excel sheet, the bullets are displayed fine, but the `<br>` tag is displayed literally. I have tried using `"\\u2028"`, but it displays a rectangular box in the excel sheet.

```
public String getProductRuleDescriptions()
{
    StringBuffer descriptions = new StringBuffer();

    for(RuleObject ruleObj : this.ruleObjectsList)
    {
        //new line if contain previous description
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String.valueOf(descriptions)))
            {
              descriptions.append("<br>");
            }
        descriptions.append("\\u2022 "+ruleObj.getDescription());

     }
     return descriptions;
 }
```

Comment: Looks like your `descriptions` already contains HTML tags. Use a real library to create Excel files like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [jexcelapi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Have you tried "\n" or "\r\n" instead of "<br>"?